# How to turn array values into variables?

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, key

I have two arrays. Like:

`Bear, prince, dog, Portugal, Bear, Clown, prince, ...`

and a second one:

`45, 67, 34, 89, ...`

I want to turn the string keys in the first array into variables and set them equal
to the numbers in the second array.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
extract(array_combine($arrayKeys, $arrayValues));
```

http://php.net/array_combine
http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

I'd recommend you keep the values in an array though, it's rarely a good idea to flood your namespace with variable variables.

Comment: So much better than the old days when you used to have to use eval for this sort of problem.

Comment: @Wes How old are these *"old days"*? PHP could do it without `evil()` since it had loops and variable variables... :)

Comment: I guess old days in my time was before I knew about `extract` which was pre 4.3.  Just shows what I know I guess.  `evil()`...nice :)

Comment: @chapagain Neither is better, really. The values should stay in an array... :)

Answer (score 5):

Try using [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) :-

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

Output:-

```
Array (
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana 
    )
```

Loop through this array and create variable for each key value:-

```
foreach($c as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Now, you can print the variables like:-

```
echo $green." , ".$red." , ".$yellow;
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I think using extract function is better way. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php But if in case, you don't want all your array values as variables (want limit variables only) then you can use my answer.

Comment: For limiting variables, I'd go with `extract(array_intersect_key($c, array_flip(array('green', 'red'))));`. ;)